# Generalized arithmetic-geometric mean and integral representation

Tags: real-analysis

Consider for $0\le b\le a$ the sequences $a_0=a,\, b_0=b$ and $a_{n+1}=\tfrac{1}{2}(a_n+b_n),\, b_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_nb_n}$ which then converge to the same number, the [arithmetic-geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean).
I found that you could easily generalize this concept to power-means (i.e. $M_p(x_1,...,x_n)=\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p\right)^{1/p}$) by defining $a_0=a,\,b_0=b$ and $a_{n+1}= M_q(a_n,b_n),\, b_{n+1}=M_p(a_n,b_n)$ for $p\le q$ (important! since $M_p\le M_q$ for $p\le q$) which converge to the same number by the exact same line of reasoning (monotone convergence and the fact that for every $p\in\mathbb{R}$: $M_p(x,y)=x$ or $M_p(x,y)=y$ implies that $x=y$).

On the Wikipedia page linked above you can also find a nice integral representation of the arithmetic-geomtric mean, obtained by considering the integral $I(a,b)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2\cos^2\theta+b^2\sin^2\theta}}d\theta$ which has the property $I(a,b)=I(\frac{1}{2}(a+b),\sqrt{ab})=I(M_1(a,b),M_0(a,b))$ (by substitution, see Wikipedia page).

My question is, if there is a similar integral representation for my generalized mean. For now, the case $p=0$ and $q\in\mathbb{R}$ would suffice.

Comment: First statement $b_0=0$ no good - then all $b_n=0$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I edited my post, it should be $b_0=b$.